# Create canvas path to avoid objects automatically

Tags: java, android, xml, canvas, line

I was working on a canvas path and require to implement more buttons and potentially images in the future. I know how to hard-code to avoid the objects that I do not require, however is there a way to do this easier? Potentially a single line of code...

So basically I have currently created a path to go from Button1 to Button2, without it passing through Button3 but rather going around it. The line I created I have hard-coded this to say go around Button3 but is there an easier way to do this, especially if there are more buttons in the future?

[Current hard-coded solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp3oa.png)

DrawView:

```
public class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
View startView;
View endView;
View obstacle;
Path path = new Path();

public DrawView(Context context, View startView, View endView, View obstacle) {
    super(context);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"));
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
    this.startView = startView;
    this.endView = endView;
    this.obstacle = obstacle;

    obstacle.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    path.moveTo(startView.getX() + startView.getWidth() / 2, startView.getY() + startView.getHeight() / 2);
    path.lineTo(obstacle.getX() + obstacle.getWidth() / 2, obstacle.getY());
    path.moveTo(obstacle.getX() + obstacle.getWidth() / 2, obstacle.getY());
    path.lineTo(obstacle.getX() + obstacle.getWidth(), obstacle.getY());
    path.moveTo(obstacle.getX() + obstacle.getWidth(), obstacle.getY());
    path.lineTo(obstacle.getX() + obstacle.getWidth(), obstacle.getY() + obstacle.getHeight());
    path.moveTo(obstacle.getX() + obstacle.getWidth(), obstacle.getY() + obstacle.getHeight());
    path.lineTo(obstacle.getX() + obstacle.getWidth() / 2, obstacle.getY() + obstacle.getHeight());
    path.moveTo(obstacle.getX() + obstacle.getWidth() / 2, obstacle.getY() + obstacle.getHeight());
    path.lineTo(endView.getX() + endView.getWidth() / 2, endView.getY() + endView.getHeight() / 2);


    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);



}


}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DrawView drawView;
    Button b1, b2, b3, clear;
    RelativeLayout rl;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        b2 = findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        b3 = findViewById(R.id.Button3);
        clear = findViewById(R.id.clear_button);

        rl = findViewById(R.id.rl);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                drawView = new DrawView(MainActivity.this, b1, b2, b3);
                rl.addView(drawView);
            }
        });


        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                rl.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.fyp.linecreator.MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You dont seen to add the drawview anywhere

Comment: Hi Marcos, `DrawView` is part of my MainActivity. It is initiated from the button onclick method

Comment: You can have  an array as parameter and loop trough then

Comment: Hi Marcos, Thanks for your suggestion. I managed to implement this - I created two arrays to capture the width range for button1 and the button3 and where the arrays conflict it goes around button3. However the issue I am finding with this implementation is that I will have to manually state which button is obstructing the line to make the polyline go around. Is there a way to find out what buttons are within a certain range for the x and y axis? I can't seem to find a method to support me with this. So for example StartView.getX(), and then find what other objects have the same x-axis value

Comment: If you cant handle do with the Rectangle (button area) and Path (line2d) method intersects so you need to do the math by yourself, will be pretty easy